# Is there an orthogonal matrix that is not unitary?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I could find a example of a unitary matrix such that is not orthogonal, thats simple in $\mathbb{C}$, but for this exercise of a orthogonal that is not unitary i realize that is possible just on $\mathbb{C}$ because all orthogonal matrix on $\mathbb{R}$ is unitary, so anyone have a exemple of this case?

Comment: Just to be clear: you're asking for a matrix $A$ with complex entries for which $AA^T = I$, but $AA^* \neq I$. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, exactly, can u help?

Comment: Note that Omnomnomnom's clarification is very important: if a matrix $A$ with *real* entries satisfies $A A^T=I$ then certainly $A A^*=I$ (since $A^*=A^T$).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{
\sqrt{2}&i\\
i&-\sqrt{2}
}
$$
satisfies $AA^T = I$ but 
$$
AA^* = \pmatrix{5&-2i\sqrt{2}\\2i\sqrt{2}&5}
$$

Comment: Almost irrelevant, but you missed a factor of $2$ in the terms outside the main diagonal, didn't you?

My calculations give $-2i\sqrt{2}$ and $2i\sqrt{2}$

Comment: @DaniloGregorin well spotted

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, as it is stated in second answer you are not right, because matrix A can not be orthogonal, by definition orthogonal matrix have real entries only. If I misunderstand something, correct me.

Comment: @Dan As I verified in my comment on the question, the asker is using the term orthogonal to refer to matrices with complex entries for which $AA^T=I$. As far as I’m concerned, whether or not this is the correct usage of the word “orthogonal” is irrelevant.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom so you've just shown matrix satisfying this condition(not orthogonal). Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 3):

*Late remark.* In general, if $K$ is complex skew-symmetric, then $Q=e^{zK}$ is complex orthogonal for every $z\in\mathbb C$. When $K\ne0$, since $e^{zK}$ is holomorphic and its power series expansion has some nonzero high-order terms, $e^{zK}$ is not a constant function. Therefore it cannot be real all the time (otherwise it will fail to satisfy Cauchy-Riemann equations). Pick a $z$ such that $Q=e^{zK}$ is not real. Then $Q$ is not unitary, because all unitary orthogonal matrices are real.